# scala.MatchError: 3099.0 (of class java.lang.Float)

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am using Spark 2.11 with Java 8 and Elasticsearch 5.4. I have a nested document structure which is as follows:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "event": {
      "properties": {
        "userId": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "event": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "properties": {
          "properties": {
            "action": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "label": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "revenue": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        },
        "receivedAt": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to fetch `event`, `userId` and `properties.revenue` fields from ES using Spark ES library. When I try to execute following code

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("es_test").setMaster("local[2]");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

Map<String, String> config = new java.util.HashMap<>();
config.put("es.read.field.include", "properties.revenue, event, userId");

Dataset<Row> ds = JavaEsSparkSQL.esDF(sqlContext, "events/timeline", config);
Dataset df = ds.select("userId", "event", "properties.revenue").filter("event = 'Completed Order'"); 

df.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> {
    System.out.println(row);
});
```

following schema tree is getting created for the Dataset which is being created here:

```
(java.lang.String) root
|-- userId: string (nullable = true)
|-- event: string (nullable = true)
|-- revenue: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
```

Here, `revenue` is being treated as an `array` whereas as per ES schema, it is defined as `float`. And, it throws following error when above mentioned code is being executed:

```
scala.MatchError: 3099.0 (of class java.lang.Float)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:154)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:241)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:379)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:58)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Looking through your schema I'm just curious why do you have such nesting of properties just inside another empty properties on the same level as userId and event. Is that intentional? See [screenshot](https://ibb.co/fPDhE5) and this json path to revenue element: mappings.event.properties. **properties.properties** .revenue

Comment: In ES, a `Map` is mapped in this way. It's just a coincidence that the ES properties keyword and my properties field have the same name but that will not cause any harm.